# Changing the left side colour of a QMenu

Tags: qt, pyside2, qtstylesheets

Hi how would I change the background colour of the left side of the menu where the icons are? Here is an example of what I'm trying to aim for:

[image: qmenu]

The colours are darkened where the icons/checkboxes are. How would I change this left gutter colour?

Comment: Simply put: you can't, as painting of QMenu items is *extremely* based on the current OS/style. You could *try* to override the QMenu `paintEvent` and draw the background *before* calling the default implementation, but that's not guaranteed to work; the only possible solution I could think of is to *completely* overrire the `paintEvent` and draw all your actions using the current style. And that's *not* an easy task.

Comment: It must be possible, the screenshot is from Maya and I'm trying to override the style using my own. I believe Maya is qt as well. Not sure how they do it but I use their `QMenu`s like normal and it comes out styled like the above picture.

Comment: Even assuming that's possible and it's a valid choice (and I still don't think it is), Maya is not written in Python. C++ is certainly more performant, and allows *faster* operations than Python. Now, it's possible to use some sort of caching mechanism and implementing some sort of "fetch more" (just like item models), but that has to be properly implemented, and the fact that you "see" a menu it doesn't mean that they're using a simple and plain QMenu to do all that.

Comment: @Flare You need to provide a [mre], otherwise it's extremely difficult for anyone else to try to reproduce the problem and suggest effective solutions. You should also state what specific OS you are testing on.